# Permission Denied changing the name of an uploaded file in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

So, I'm trying to change the name of a file that already exists in my app but it throws the error "Permission denied". The directory where the file is stored has 777 permissions and it's on the pubic/ directory and the user owner of the file is apache user but only of the file, my user is the owner of the director which stores the file.

Also I've changed the user to mine but still got the error.

I have searched for solutions but got none.

Any ideas or help will really be appreciated :)

Here's the code:

//Controller

```
//Here I get the data of file I want to update.
$act = Act::find($request->id);

//Here I get the last slug name of the file
$filename = $act->filename;

//Here I set the new name of the file
$act->name = $request->name;

//Here I set the new slug name for the file
$act->filename = str_slug($request->name);

//Here I validate if there is a new file to upload
if($request->hasFile('filename'))
{
    //If true, I get the extension, delete the old file and save the new file with the new slug name.
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    File::delete(public_path('documents/acts'), $filename.'.pdf');
    $file->move(public_path('documents/acts'), str_slug($act->filename).'.'.$extension);
}
else
{
    //If false, I just want to change the slug name of the old file to the new slug name **Here it throws the error**
    File::move('documents/acts/'.$filename.'.pdf', 'documents/acts/'.$act->filename.'.pdf');
}

//And finally, here I save.
$act->save();
```

**Solution**
ONly to take out the public_path in the rename line :)

Comment: Make sure that your directory already exist.

Comment: Post the user and group as well as the file permissions you see from the filesystem in your question. Is it owned by the same user?

Comment: @mrabbani yes, it exists.

Comment: @btl when the file is uploaded the user owner and group is www-data.